# issues installing imagick for macOS

Tags: php, macos, localhost, imagick, xampp-vm

edit: After some further errors, I'm stuck at this:

```
make: *** [imagick_file.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

As I understand, this seems to be a compatibility problem with the PHP-Version. Is there any possibility to solve this?

---

---

I'm using XAMPP on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 to run a PHP-testserver and need to install imagick, but experience some issues.

When I run the following command in Terminal:

```
pecl install imagick
```

...I get an error message:

```
WARNING: configuration download directory "/private/var/tmp/pear/download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
.....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/lib/php/doc/imagick/examples
```

I'm an absolute beginner, so I would be really grateful, to get some explanations, how to make this work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try sudo

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that helped a bit, but now I get "ERROR: 'phpize' failed" and it also says "Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script".

Comment: You had a permissions problem that sudo solved. I would thank you upvote so original problem was fixed. In the other hand, you comment about "ERROR: 'phpize' failed" and edit question writing about "[imagick_file.lo]". What are current circumstances? Have you tried with https://www.php.net/manual/es/imagick.requirements.php ? Which is your PHP version?